# How to keep hover state on select mat card with material elevation directive

Tags: angular, select, hover

I have 3 mat cards which are elevated when the mouse interact with them.
The goal is to keep the over state on the selected mat card (modal is changed with `click()`

The stack : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-elevation-hover-yxt5ph?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Have you tried using ngClass?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a class with the same properties that the element has when hover, and add/remove that class to the element with click event

**CSS**

```
div.target:hover,
.mouseclick{
    "properties"
}
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector("div.target").onclick =
function(this){
   if(this.classList.indexof("mouseclick") == -1){
        this.classList.add(".mouseclick");
    }else{
        this.classList.remove(".mouseclick")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use ngClass. You can bind a variable to a css class and toggle it based on that variable.

It would look something like this:

**.html**

```
<mat-card [ngClass]="{'text-success':clicked === 'card1'}" appMaterialElevation (click)="select(titles[0])">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{titles[0]}}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <p>
            This card changes elevation when you hover over it!
        </p>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**.ts**

```
@Component{...}
clicked: string = '';

select(clickedVar: string) {
    this.clicked = card1
}
```

Repeat as necessary for your cards. Just define a css class for the style you want when clicked.

See more on it here: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Comment: did it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-elevation-hover-8ztsjn?file=src/app/app.component.css how is it ?

Comment: @sowebull Looks great! I think you used it very effectively. Play around with it and see what you come up with. It's a very handy little feature that Angular has boxed in with the framework.

Comment: actually there is a problem when you hover on the select matcard

Comment: it applies the css hover state on the selected mat card that already has its hover css state

Comment: you'll have to remove the css class previously applied, let me check your code quick and figure it out

Comment: I think your directive is overriding your 'ngClass' annotation. I would look into that a bit more, I'm not exactly sure how that plays together.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have refactor your code and it work you can find the stack here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-elevation-hover-kpypah

first you have to create class title with isSelected Property that change when item is selected .

and if i have refactor he html to use NgFor
and last i have add an css class to manage the hover event

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  defaultElevation = 2;
  raisedElevation = 8;

  titles:title[] = [{name:'title1'}, {name:'title2'},{name:'title3'}];
  titleSelected;

  name = 'Angular';

  select(title) {
    // clear all selection
    this.titles.map(t=>t.isSelected = false);
    // select the current item
    title.isSelected = true;
    this.titleSelected = title;
    
  }
}

export class title {
  name: string;
  isSelected?: boolean;
}
```

```css
mat-card:hover  {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

```html
<p>Title selected : {{ titleSelected?.name }}</p>


<ng-container *ngFor="let item of titles">
<mat-card (click)="select(item)" 
  [class.mat-elevation-z2]="!item.isSelected" 
  [class.mat-elevation-z8]="item.isSelected">
 <mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-title>{{item.name}}</mat-card-title>
 </mat-card-header>
 <mat-card-content>
  <p>
   This card changes elevation when you hover over it!
  </p>
 </mat-card-content>
</mat-card><br>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: looks great, i tried to pixellate a bit more the selected mat card but got some troubles

Comment: can you describe the trouble you have